# vm extension from storage account in terraform

Tags: terraform, virtual-machine, azure-blob-storage

Trying to create VM extension in terraform. file stored in Azure storage account.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "VMextn1" {
    name                 = "avmextn1"
    virtual_machine_id = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.vm.id
    publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
    type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
    type_handler_version = "1.10"
    auto_upgrade_minor_version = true
    settings             = <<SETTINGS
      {
          "fileUris": ["https://iotstorage15081.blob.core.windows.net/scriptscont/installNodeJS.ps1"],
          "commandToExecute": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file installNodeJS.ps1"      
      }
  SETTINGS
  }
```

able to access file from VM by logging into it. but not able to do it from terraform. when executed, it is going into infinite loop i guess. below is the error:

```
Error: Future#WaitForCompletion: context has been cancelled: StatusCode=200 -- Original Error: context deadline exceeded
```

Answer (score 0):

This error may cause the azure default timeouts is minimum. When we use custom script extension that runs for longer than an expected and it started failing on us with error

Try to add `timeouts` block on Resource

```cpp
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "test" {
  name     = "test-resource-group"
  location = "West Europe"

  timeouts {
    create = "20m"
    delete = "40m"
  }
}
```

And try to use updated provider version like below:

```cpp
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=3.0.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Reference:  [Resource Timeouts for creation terraform-provider-azurerm](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/171) by Tom Harvey

Comment: thank you for the suggestions. i will implement the above.